# Any danger in editing xcode source files in the editor of my choice?

Tags: xcode

I occasionally look over my Xcode source files in Emacs, which I am very comfortable with. I gather that Apple has removed the ability to specify an alternate editor in Xcode 4. But if I edit the files in Emacs sometimes, am I in danger of getting Xcode into some kind of deeply confused state, ie. "hosed" in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit individual files, then no it's fine. The problem might come if you've got Xcode open at the same time. If the Xcode editor has that file open and you accidentally save you would save over it. But that's just the same as using 2 editors.

If you start playing with the actual Xcode project files however, then the gloves are off!

Answer (score 0):

I routinely edit my Phonegap files in Dreamweaver or TextMate and have not had an issue.